# strange instruction in IDA when debugging malware

Tags: ida, debugging

What does `mov edi, ds:RegCloseKey` actually   do ?

Does it call `RegCloseKey` and the registry is "closed"?

The whole function looks like

```
call  ds:RegOpenKeyEXW    
test  eax,eax    
jnz   loc_12345    
push  push 300h    
lea   eax, [ebp-0C64h]
push  eax 
push  esi 
push  dword ptr [rbp-0C64h]
call  ds:RegEnumKeyW
mov   edi ds:RegCloseKey
```

Comment: it might use edi to call the function it is an optimisation     if the function needs to called several times call edi takes less space than call regclosekey()

Comment: it's probably not "the whole function", please edit and add the rest.

Answer (score 2):

No, it means it's storing the address for later use, what comes after that segment? Something in the line of "CALL EDI" I'm guessing.

Answer (score 1):

It is certainly preparing to call it, we can speculate (why else reference it?).

**RegCloseKey** is simply used to close an open handle to the registry. It doesn't 'shut down' the registry, as your question seemed to imply (to me anyway). It is just another handle close function, but applies to registry handles. Those that come from any Registry function - RegOpenKey, RegCreateKeyEx, etc..